# Create blog post links similar to a folder structure

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

I am currently working on a blog where I would like to create links to my individual articles in the following form:

```
http://www.mysite.com/health/2013/08/25/some-random-title
                      ------            -----------------
                        |                       |
                     category                 title
```

However I have no idea how to achieve this.

I have found something that would give me the URI.

```
$uri = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
```

I would then go ahead and extract the needed parts and make requests against the database. 
This may seem a very very dumb question, but I do not know how to look this up on google (I tried...) but how exactly am I going to handle the link ?

I try to explain it step-by-step:

User clicks on article title -> the page reloads with new uri --> Where am I supposed to handle this new uri and how ? If the request path looked like this:

`index.php?title=some-random-article-title`

I would do it in the index.php and read the $_GET array and process it accordingly. But how do I do it with the proposed structure at the beginning of this question ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need a few things:

1. Setup an .htaccess to redirect all request to your main file which will handle all that, something like:

   ```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
   </IfModule>
   ```

   The above will redirect all request of non-existent files and folder to your `index.php`
2. Now you want to handle the URL Path so you can use the PHP variable **`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`** as you have mentioned.
3. From there is pretty much parse the result of it to extract the information you want, you could use one of the functions `parse_url` or `pathinfo` or `explode`, to do so.

Using `parse_url` which is probably the most indicated way of doing this:

```
$s = empty($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) ? '' : ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") ? "https" : "http";
$url = $s . '://' . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
var_dump(parse_url($url));
```

Output:

```
["scheme"] => string(4) "http" 
["host"]   => string(10) "domain.com" 
["path"]   => string(36) "/health/2013/08/25/some-random-title" 
["query"]  => string(17) "with=query-string"
```

So `parse_url` can easily break down the current URL as you can see.

For example using `pathinfo`:

```
$path_parts = pathinfo($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

`$path_parts['dirname']` would return `/health/2013/08/25/`

`$path_parts['basename']` would return `some-random-title` and if it had an extension it would return `some-random-title.html`

`$path_parts['extension']` would return empty and if it had an extension it would return `.html`

`$path_parts['filename']` would return `some-random-title` and if it had an extension it would return `some-random-title.html`

Using explode something like this:

```
$parts = explode('/', $path);
foreach ($parts as $part)
    echo $part, "\n";
```

Output:

```
health
2013
08
25
some-random-title.php
```

Of course these are just examples of how you could read it.

You could also use .htaccess to make specific rules instead of handling everything from one file, for example:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/?$ blog.php?category=$1&date=$2-$3-$4&title=$5 [L]
```

Basically the above would break down the URL path and internally redirect it to your file blog.php with the proper parameters, so using your URL sample it would redirect to:

```
http://www.mysite.com/blog.php?category=health&date=2013-08-25&title=some-random-title
```

However on the client browser the URL would remain the same:

```
http://www.mysite.com/health/2013/08/25/some-random-title
```

There are also other functions that might come handy into this for example [**`parse_url`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php), [**`pathinfo`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) like I have mentioned early, server variables, etc...

Comment: Brilliant ! Works like a charm!

Comment: @MartinE. give it another read have update with some more content which may be interesting.

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort Prix, I will definitely take a closer look into this !

Comment: There is one problem though... I seem to lose the path to my stylesheet. Is there any way to fix that ?

Comment: Use the absolute path for example `http://domain.com/css/style.css`, if you use relative paths it will take the current folder as its folder.

Comment: Is that the only solution ? That might be a little tedious eventually. For now it works...

Comment: @MartinE. well yes and no, if you keep all the css on a single folder or on an identifiable one you can use a RewriteRule to change the path automatically. `RewriteRule (css/.*\.css)$ /$1 [R=301,L]` untested but could work.

Comment: Well, there is more to that than just stylesheets, it is also images, fonts and so on, so I think I might have to go with absolute paths for now. Thank you.

Comment: Do like others CMS do and have predefined variables that you can easily attach to the html that will place the rest of the URL for you ;)

Comment: For example have a `config.php` file with some basic information that is often used `$url = 'http://domain.com'; $css = $url . '/css'; $images = $url . '/images';` Then you can just append it to your style or image HTML code `echo 'rest of the code....src="' . $css . '/style.css"... rest of the code'`

Comment: ok I understood correctly :) Ok I will do that... Still tedious, but better. Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: Nothing much else you can that is also used by widely known CMS's like wordpress and others.

Answer (score 1):

This is called Semantic URLs, they're also referred to as slugified URLs.

You can do this with the `.htaccess` command `RewriteURL`

Ex:

```
RewriteURL ^(.*)$   handler.php?path=$1
```

Now `handler.php` gets `/health/2013/08/25/some-random-title` and this is your entry point.

Comment: I think you mean `RewriteRule`, not `RewriteURL`.