# Using Apache mod_rewrite to send all requests to a file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

How can I use mod_rewrite to send certain types of incoming urls to a particular file on the server?

Ideally any html requests would load a file (eg /var/www/sites/urlprocessor.php) which would then determine what is being requested and the display the appropriate content based on the url.

Example: Say I wanted a url to list some 'cars'. I would want the following URLs to load the urlprocessor.php file instead of loading the actual page and instead of doing a redirect.

```
http://www.mydomain.com/cars.html --> /var/www/sites/urlprocessor.php
http://www.mydomain.com/cars.htm  --> /var/www/sites/urlprocessor.php
http://www.mydomain.com/cars      --> /var/www/sites/urlprocessor.php
```

On the flip-side, non-html requests (jpgs, pdfs, etc) would continue on normally without loading the urlprocessor.php file.

I am currently using the last line of code in the following to accomplish this. It 301 redirects all html page requests to 'index.html' which then loads the urlprocessor.php file. I prefer to just load the file without the 301 redirect.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule !^.*(\.gif|\.GIF|\.png|\.mp3|\.m3u|\.js|\.jpg|\.JPG|\.css|\.swf|\.flv|\.ico|\.wav|\.doc|\.DOC|\.pdf|\.PDF|\.xls|\.XLS|\.txt|\.TXT)$ index.html [L]
```

Is there a way to go directly to a file without doing the redirect?

Thanks!!

Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that `/var/www/` is the root folder then this would work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . /sites/urlprocessor.php [L]
```

Basically this will redirect any non-existent folder and file to the `urlprocessor.php`

**[For more information on how to handle the redirect with your PHP you can refer yourself to this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499398/create-blog-post-links-similar-to-a-folder-structure/18499460#18499460)**

Comment: Appreciate your help Prix. Question about your meaning of the root directory. Will this redirect to an actual file in a folder on the server (full path = /var/www/sites/processor.php) or just to a file in the htdocs directory (http://www.mydomain.com/urlprocessor.php)?

Comment: @TomS. you can only redirect to what is inside the root folder of the virtualhost. So if the root folder of the virtualhost is `/var/www/` then you can use `/sites/urlprocessor.php` and it will use `/var/www/sites/urlprocessor.php` however if its a file outside the root then it will not work. To use a file and/or folder that is not inside the virtualhost you could try using a symbolic link which on linux can be create with the command `ln -s /path/to/file /destination/filename` then you would be able to use files outside of it given they have the proper permission to allow it.