# Direct Apache requests under a certain URL directory to one file, and all others to a second file

Tags: php, angular, apache

I'm trying to host both an Angular app and an extremely simple, one-file PHP CRUD API backend, both in Apache on my Raspberry Pi 3.

I want to configure the rule rewrites (via the mod_rewrite, which I do have enabled) to direct requests first to files/directories that already exist exist.  Then, I need requests to the API (that is, requests in the form of `~/api.php/{table}/{id}`) to be directed to the PHP file.  From then on, all requests to all other places should be directed to the Angular dist's index.html (I've run `ng build` and put the resulting files onto my server, with those darned files set to "public" as per hours of me spinning my wheels)

Essentially, I need to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18626916/using-apache-mod-rewrite-to-send-all-requests-to-a-file), but twice:  once for a subdirectory, and once again for all other directories.

I'm very new to the Apache configuration files (Let's see... 2 hours in?), and I'm sure this is a fairly simple thing to do, but thus far my limited understanding of the configuration tools has prevented me from coming up with a solution.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

After long last, I did eventually figure this out.  Turns out, I was doing several things wrong (go figure).

My first fatal falacy was that I was doing my business in `.htaccess` files, and incorrectly so at that.  The first issue I discovered is that `.htaccess` files are *bad* and to be avoided, and should be completely ignored if you can use the global config in conjunction with  `<Directory "/var/www/html/..."></Directory>` statements.  The second mistake I made (Note:  I made this after posting the above question) is that .htaccess rules are not applied in the hierarchical structure I'd assumed;  just the opposite, in fact.  `.Htaccess` config files in lower subdirectories are in fact overridden by their higher directory kin, not the other way around.

My second mistake was actually in how I was using the RewriteRule statements.  For anyone else just trying to get by with Apache, and not interested in learning its inner mechanics, keep in mind that you'll probably actually save more time than you lose by giving the [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html) a read.  That's true for most anything, actually.

The code that finally did the trick can be found below.  (This is from the `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` file, edited via `sudo nano` through an SSH connection)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
# The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
# the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
# redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
# specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
# match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
# value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
# However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
#ServerName www.example.com

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

# Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
# modules, e.g.
#LogLevel info ssl:warn

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

# For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
# enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
# include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
# following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
# after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
#Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<Directory "/var/www/html/">
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/api
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</Directory>
<Directory "/var/www/html/api/">
    RewriteBase /api/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /api/api.php/$1 [L]
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

This redirects all requests not beginning with `/api/` (`/home` or `/faq`, for example) to Angular's index.html, and any API requests (`api/People/27` or `/api/Customers`) to the `api.php` file (located in `/api/api.php`).

**Edit:**  By accident, I found an issue with the above code where it did not forward the actual URL to `api.php` for it to do its magic.  This has been corrected by matching with a `^(.*)$` and plumbing that answer to the redirected rule with a `$1`