# Use Apache to send all requests for a given directory to a single file

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to do something that I think should be simple, but I can't get it to work...

I want to set up my .htaccess file so that any requests to a directory (or to any file within that directory or subdirectory) will actually return a file in a different directory.

In other words, any of the following requests (with or without query parameters):

```
/dummy
/dummy/
/dummy/foo
/dummy/foo/
/dummy/bar.html
/dummy/foo/bar.html
/dummy/abc/def/ghi/jkl/boo.txt
```

should *all* return the file at

```
/testing/test.php
```

Note that the **/dummy** directory doesn't actually exist at all.

Ideally, it shouldn't be possible to return the **/testing/test.php** file directly, but that's not a dealbreaker. However, if query parameters are included in the original request, then they should be passed to **/testing/test.php**. It would be great if the PHP code in **/testing/test.php** could determine what the original request URI was, but that's really a separate PHP question.

I found a similar question at [Using Apache mod_rewrite to send all requests to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18626916/using-apache-mod-rewrite-to-send-all-requests-to-a-file) which linked to [Create blog post links similar to a folder structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499398/create-blog-post-links-similar-to-a-folder-structure/18499460#18499460), but I can't seem to get it to work in my case, even though I've been playing with the assorted directory values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use these rules in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On 

# prevent direct access to /testing/test.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+testing/test\.php[?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]

# rewrite everything that starts with /dummy to /testing/test.php
RewriteRule ^dummy(/.*)?$ /testing/test.php [NC,L]
```

Note that query string in original request will automatically be forwarded to `/testing/test.php`. Also you can get original request URI using php variable:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly something like this

```
RewriteEngine On 
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^dummy/(.*) testing/test.php?_REQUEST=$1 [NC,L]
```