# PHP show page which doesn't exist

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'am trying to set up a simple CMS and actually everything works.

Except of this one point where I've got no idea how to solve it.

There is the page index.html and a .htaccess with the content

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

Now this works good, I don't know if it is a good solution though (?)

The problem is how can I call now a subpage?

So there is a link in the nav with

```
   <a href="/foo.html">FOO</a>
```

Now if I click on it the url is www.mydomain.com/foo.html but how can I show the content if there is no page

> /foo.html

There must be a solution for this without creating all the pages or how can I do it?

Comment: you haven't named the CMS ...

Comment: @RajeevRanjan sorry no name. it's self made, you can call it how ever you like ;-) that's the problem. now I wonder how to handle the question

Comment: Are you asking about a 404 page handler?

Comment: I'm asking for a solution. I've got no idea how to handle. I just don't believe I have to write a page for every link. so I'm wondering how to set up the index.php to also show the content for those other pages. I can get the contents with a php function no problem but I never have a page like the uri wants to have it

Comment: @caramba [this might be of your interest since you're making your own blog and wants to use friendly URLs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499398/create-blog-post-links-similar-to-a-folder-structure/18499460#18499460)

Comment: @caramba glad you liked it ;)

Comment: bluddy good answer there!  looks like I can delete my question cause seems verry much like a duplicate now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put a line in your .htaccess file to rewrite the urls to call index.php which will then process the remainder of your path as an input to a function.
something like

> RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?$1

that will then allow your index.php script to parse the path ($1) as a GET parameter and fetch/generate the correct response.

EDIT:
Here is an example of .htaccess:

> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteBase /
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

The !-f and !-d in the conditions mean "not a file" and "not a directory" (i.e. only fire the rule if the URL doesn't exist as an actual file or directory)

The %{QUERY_STRING} allows the inclusion of any GET parameters along with the url path matched by $1

Comment: RewriteRule sounds very good. But this one gives me an "Internal Server Error" any idea what it could be? +1 cause I know now what i can type in google which shows me lots of ways with the rewriterule, thanks

Comment: this error often means that there is an error in your .htaccess file. I will edit my answer to include an example of a simple .htaccess file i have for one of my projects.

Comment: thanks for your help loopo. the problem is (*.) in the first code line of the .htaccess now with (.*) it will work. thinking about to remove this question cause it's a duplicate of the link user Prix showed in the comments above. I just didn't know how to search for it. rewriteRule and how to would of been the right answer and question... thanks