# .htaccess to redirect parts of a URL to local files

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a custom web app and the file structure works like this:

```
/apps/calendar/frontend/index.php
/apps/calendar/frontend/view/index.php
/apps/calendar/backend/index.php
/apps/calendar/backend/edit/index.php
/apps/calendar/backend/add/index.php
/apps/calendar/backend/view/index.php
```

I'm trying to write a .htaccess file to help redirect the files so  they cant see the 'real' path.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/(.*)/(.*)($|/$) /apps/$1/frontend/$2/$3 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/(.*)($|/$) /apps/$1/frontend/$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)($|/$) /apps/$1/frontend/ [NC,L]
```

When I visit localhost/calendar it should map redirect to /apps/calendar/frontend/index.php. But when I visit localhost/calendar/add it gives me a 301 (permanent move) then shows the full page of localhost/apps/calendar/frontend/add/index.php in the console. Anyone got any ideas why this would happen? Or a better way around this? The apps might have heaps of sub-directories so, I'm not particularly keen on having a rule for ever subdirectory combination.

As you can see also I have a /admin path, which would load the /backend/ parts of the app. I would assuming I can do the similar code with the prefix of /admin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This question might also be of your interest: [Create blog post links similar to a folder structure.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499398/create-blog-post-links-similar-to-a-folder-structure)**

Given that your `.htaccess` is located on the root folder of your domain `/home/youraccount/public_html/.htaccess`, it would look like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(admin|apps) [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/apps/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?(|.*)$ /apps/$1/frontend/$2 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/apps [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/apps/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^admin/([^/]+)/?(|.*)$ /apps/$1/backend/$2 [NC,L]
```

Let's say the user access:

```
http://domain.com/calendar
http://domain.com/calendar/
http://domain.com/calendar/add
```

All the above would redirect to

```
/apps/calendar/frontend/index.php
/apps/calendar/frontend/index.php/
/apps/calendar/frontend/index.php/add
```

And the if the user access:

```
http://domain.com/calendar/admin
http://domain.com/calendar/admin/
http://domain.com/calendar/admin/add
```

It would go to:

```
/apps/calendar/backend/index.php
/apps/calendar/backend/index.php/
/apps/calendar/backend/index.php/add
```

So it would make `index.php` your controller for each end:

```
/apps/calendar/frontend/index.php
/apps/calendar/backend/index.php
```

Comment: Thanks.. Just some tweaks though to suit my app structure. The /frontend would be directly loaded by public users. While the /backend files are loaded via AJAX using $.load() inside pages of /admin. So it should be /admin/apps/calendar/index.php; /admin/apps/calendar/add

Comment: Sorry, also how can I allow the /index.php to load? Adding: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^index.php [NC] to the conditions doesnt work for me. Any ideas?

Comment: `/admin/apps/calendar/` but it would be accessed from `http://domain.com/admin/calendar`? With the current setup `index.php` would only show if you append it to the URL's on your HTML.

Comment: Nice! Is it possible not to use a controller in /apps/calendar/frontend/index.php ? So if it were /calendar/add it would just redirect to /apps/calendar/frontend/add/index.php ?

Comment: Just an idea but try the update and see if that works like u want.

Comment: I get a 301 error on /calendar/add and redirects to /apps/calendar/frontend//add/ and I can see the change in the address bar. (is it my machine?). Backend is all sweet though! Thanks

Comment: @Ourx forgot to remove a `/`, try now. Also, `/apps/calendar/frontend/add` exists right?

Comment: Ah I see.. Needed to have a / at the end of /calendar/add/ to work. Is there a way to either drop the slash or force a slash?

Comment: @Ourx If you drop the slash it won't lead to the `index.php`, but if u remove `-MultiViews` and I guess it will work. [**Don't forget to mark this answer if it solved your issue, see here how.**](http://stackoverflow.com/about)