# Redirecting URLs after mod_rewrite?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to understand how the mod_rewrite works. For example, if I have a URL like:

```
example.com/user.php?id=123
```

And with the mod_rewrite I can create the URL Like:

```
example.com/user/123
```

Now this is ok, but on other locations in my application, I have linked to the user page using the old format , eg:

```
<a href="user.php?id=123">123</a>
```

Now does it mean that I would need to change all these links manually and should link according to the new format? eg:

```
<a href="user/123">123</a>
```

Or should this be done with the mod_rewrite too?
I'm not using any PHP framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the long run yes you would have to change it but you can also redirect that:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Externally redirect /user.php?id=123 to /user/123
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(user)\.php\?id=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]

# Internally forward /user/123 to /user.php?id=123
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9]+)/?$ /user.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

The external redirect is the one that changes the URL on the browser, the internally is the one that does not change the URL but shows the content of the other place in question.

While the above would redirect the user from:

```
example.com/user.php?id=123
```

To

```
example.com/user/123
```

It would be for the best if you change your links to use the SEO friendly ones to avoid the extra redirect all the time a user access or navigate on your website.

Comment: Thanks, its clear to me now. I will not use .htaccess to redirect the URLs, instead I will change them to new format in my application.

Comment: @user2738640 [here is another answer I've replied that might also be of your interest.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499398/create-blog-post-links-similar-to-a-folder-structure) To put it simple, if you have a controller you can go as far as make your own routing system from your code using a simple rule on your `.htaccess`

Answer (score -2):

find all links in db and replace

```
UPDATE `myTable`
SET myCol = REPLACE(myCol, '<a href="user.php?id=', '<a href="user/')
WHERE keyCol = testKey;
```

to do the entire table, remove `WHERE` clause

i think that will work, i dont play with sql much nowadays

Comment: That is IF he is using MySQL to store the links and if its the way you've assumed he does it.

Comment: yes i did assume. i assumed if you are good with db's you would not ask here, and if you used another db type like PostgreSQL you still wouldn't ask because you are good with db's ;) and i dont mind flat files but db's are much more flexible...to many assumptions, i'll cut it out

Comment: He never stated he is using a db for that he is asking a `.htaccess` question with portion of how his HTML looks like currently. He also never tagged it with any db tags.

Comment: @gwillie Thanks for your answer, however it has nothing to do with the db. I only store IDs the db, not the whole url, that would not make much sense imo.

Comment: @Prix and user2738640, you are more than right, i assumed far to much :)