# How to get the .htaccess mod_rewrite to work?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

Here are several examples of the URLs:

```
domain.com/?view=home&action=update
domain.com/?view=home&page=1&action=update
domain.com/?view=home&action=update&page=2&sort=desc
domain.com/?view=home&sort=desc&page=2&action=update
```

How do I make my .htaccess to rewrite the URLs (any of the formats above) to he following structure:

```
domain.com/home/1/desc/update
```

The quantity of get parameters is different in different cases, as well as the order of the parameters.

Besides, I need to be able to **$_GET** the values after they've been rewritten in PHP.

The application will be utilizing the following keys for the query-string:

```
view, item, page, sort, dir, action.
```

All of these are optional and I might need to add some more later on.

I tried all of these separate, none worked:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/([^?]*)$ /index.php?$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?params=$1 [NC]
```

Thanks.

Comment: what rules have you tried?

Comment: Added to original question

Comment: I know I need to learn mod rewrite and regex better, but now I have a task I need to take care of.

Comment: Here is one way to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18499460/342740

Comment: @Prix, won't work as in this example the query keys are in strict order while in my case they are not.

Comment: @Piero it doesn't matter what the query order is if you redirect all of it to a index as shown on my example and threat it from it.

Comment: @Prix, what I meant to say is that in the example $_GET keys are lost, and $_GET is re-indexed with numeric keys. This would work in case if the order of the parameters was consistent. Thus $_GET[0] would hold the value of $_GET['view']. In my case, however, the value of $_GET['view'] may be held by any element of the $_GET array and at the same time $_GET[0] may hold the value for $_GET['action'], for example. This way in the PHP I won't be able to identify which index is holding necessary value, and thus, order does matter.

Comment: Why would this question be considered a duplicate, if the case is unique? The situation where the order and the quantity of the $_GET parameters is random is not discussed in the question referenced above.

Comment: @Piero no it doesn't matter because you don't need to rely on the index since the get element gives you the key and the value you can sort it by the key. Also in your pretty URL you have a pattern where the number is always the page and you can easily figure the other 2 options since sorting will pretty much be asc or desc which you can resolve with a single check. You should also keep your URL organized google-wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than rewriting to `domain.com/home/1/desc/update`, it sounds to me like you would like users to be able to click on a link like this: `domain.com/home/1/desc/update`, and for that url to be internally rewritten to the query form so you can extract the variables in PHP (users will not see the query url).

You gave us an example of a url with four variables: `domain.com/home/1/desc/update`, but elsewhere you say that there are two more: `dir` and `item`.

In order to reliably extract parameters from a url like `domain.com/home/1/desc/update`, it has to be of a reliable format. Therefore,

- Either you make sure that each url contains the six parameters, for instance `domain.com/home/1/desc/update/dir_value/item_value`
- Or you include the key name in the url, so that the url' "folders" are a series of key-value pairs: `domain.com/view/home/page/1/sort/desc/action/update`

Once you have made that choice, rewriting becomes possible, but not before then.

Comment: Accepted, thank you. Picked first option and adjusted with php to my needs.

Answer (score 1):

> The quantity of get parameters is different in different cases, as
>   well as the order of the parameters.

That’s a problem. The thing with [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) is you need some kind of structure in place to filter the nice SEO friendly URL of `domain.com/home/1/desc/update` to something like `domain.com/?view=home&page=1&sort=desc&action=update`. So something like this would work for you to capture any or all segments but in a specific order:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/?([^/]*)$ index.php?q=$1&$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?view=$1&sort=$2&page=$3&action=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?view=$1&sort=$2&page=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?view=$1&sort=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?view=$1 [L]
```

And if you place the following code in `index.php`:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_GET);
echo '</pre>';
```

The output would be:

```
Array
(
    [view] => home
    [sort] => 1
    [page] => desc
    [action] => update
)
```

But if you are positive you need to deal with randomly structured SEO friendly URLs then this rule should work:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url_path=$1 [L]
```

Now that will not redirect anything, but it will capture the whole path of `/home/1/desc/update` and set it in a `$_GET` array with a key named `url_path`. You can then check the contents in that variable in your `index.php` like this:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_GET);
echo '</pre>';

$segments = explode('/', $_GET['url_path']);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($segments);
echo '</pre>';
```

And the output of that would be this:

```
Array
(
    [url_path] => home/1/desc/update
)

Array
(
    [0] => home
    [1] => 1
    [2] => desc
    [3] => update
)
```

Comment: Well the problem in this case is that keys are lost for the $_GET array, instead indexes are provided, which don't help when the order of the key-value pairs is random.