# Mod Rewrite: different domains with different languages

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm developing a multiple languages website. I'm using a different subdomain for each language and they're poiting to the same folder. It's the same site using .po files for translation.

Now, I'm working with pretty urls, and I need each subdomain to have it's own set of rules.

For example:

```
en.domain.com/contact
pt.domain.com/contato
es.domain.com/contacto
```

My simplified htaccess looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^en.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^contact/$ /contact.php 
RewriteRule ^contact$ /contact.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^pt.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^contato/$ /contact.php
RewriteRule ^contato$ /contact.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^es.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^contacto/$ /contact.php
RewriteRule ^contacto$ /contact.php [L]


</ifModule>
```

The problem is that, if I try a custom url from one domain on another, it still works. For example, the "/contato" word in portuguese still opens the "/contact" url on the english.

So what I want is, that each domain ONLY follows it's specif set of rules, not every single rule on the file. Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you send everything to a main controller aka "index.php" and handle it from your code side, it will be 10 times easier and in the future you can easily switch it any way you want. [Here is an example or how it would look like, except you would need to further parse the host variable to catch the language, as you use it as a subdomain.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18499460/342740)

Comment: Because when I do that I keep getting a 404 error on the headers, though the site works ok. I'm afraid that this 404 header might affect google rankings.

Comment: you get 404 because you're doing something wrong, check your logs and other information to see where you're doing it wrong, to where its being redirect and to where it should have been redirected to.

Comment: Also why do you have 2 `RewriteRule` for each `RewriteCond` here?

Comment: @anubhava one for "/contact" and another one for "/contact/"

Comment: @Prix I just find out that adding  -MultiViews fixed my problem. Gonna keep the question, because there might be another scenario where I need exclusive rules for exclusive subdomains.